# Unable to import Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm following [this tutorial](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/) and I'm getting stuck on Tweepy installation. I ran `sudo pip install tweepy` as per the instructions from [Tweepy's github page](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) and the installation was successful:

**Successful Installation**

```
User-MBP:Mercuria user$ sudo pip install tweepy
Downloading/unpacking tweepy
  Downloading tweepy-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking requests>=2.4.3 (from tweepy)
  Downloading requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (470kB): 470kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.7.3 (from tweepy)
  Downloading six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1 (from tweepy)
  Downloading requests_oauthlib-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking oauthlib>=0.6.2 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1->tweepy)
  Downloading oauthlib-1.0.3.tar.gz (109kB): 109kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/oauthlib/setup.py) egg_info for package oauthlib

Installing collected packages: tweepy, requests, six, requests-oauthlib, oauthlib
  Found existing installation: requests 2.1.0
    Uninstalling requests:
      Successfully uninstalled requests
  Found existing installation: requests-oauthlib 0.4.0
    Uninstalling requests-oauthlib:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-oauthlib
  Found existing installation: oauthlib 0.6.1
    Uninstalling oauthlib:
      Successfully uninstalled oauthlib
  Running setup.py install for oauthlib

Successfully installed tweepy requests six requests-oauthlib oauthlib
Cleaning up...
```

**Exception**

```
User-MBP:Mercuria user$ python feed.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feed.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
ImportError: No module named tweepy.streaming
```

The code I'm running can be found in the tutorial page, and is also pasted below here:

**Code**

```
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET"
consumer_key = "ENTER YOUR API KEY"
consumer_secret = "ENTER YOUR API SECRET"


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])
```

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: @Maikflow Python 2.7.6

Comment: Try `import tweepy; print tweepy.__file__` what does that print?

Comment: @AnandSKumar `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feed.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy; print tweepy.__file__
ImportError: No module named tweepy`

Comment: Try - `which python` and then `which pip` ?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pip` and `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: do you have different versions of python in your system? Try `which pip2` ?

Comment: I get `/usr/local/bin/pip2`

Comment: What about `which pip3` ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
For me it was due to multiple versions of python installed on my system.
I had to do the following to fix it:
For v2.7

```
pip install tweepy
```

For v3.0

```
pip3 install tweepy
```

For v3.5:

```
pip3.5 install tweepy
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to try to use pip version of your python version. If you have python 2.7.7 just run: sudo pip2.7 install tweepy
It worked for me in python 2.7.6.

```
>>> from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
>>> dir(StreamListener)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'keep_alive', 'on_connect', 'on_data', 'on_delete', 'on_direct_message', 'on_disconnect', 'on_error', 'on_event', 'on_exception', 'on_friends', 'on_limit', 'on_status', 'on_timeout', 'on_warning']
```

Why are you trying from tweepy.streaming instead of just tweepy?

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
>>> import tweepy
>>> from tweepy import StreamListener
>>> dir(StreamListener)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'keep_alive', 'on_connect', 'on_data', 'on_delete', 'on_direct_message', 'on_disconnect', 'on_error', 'on_event', 'on_exception', 'on_friends', 'on_limit', 'on_status', 'on_timeout', 'on_warning']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`StreamListener` is a class in `tweepy` package, so you need to import it from `tweepy` not from `tweepy.stream`, modify your code with corrected import.

in Line #2

```
from tweepy import StreamListener
```

Also use an IDE (PyCharm preferred), so you don't make these small mistakes while coding.